# When is $n = \frac{a_{1}x^{2} + a_{2}x + a_{3}}{a_{4}x + a_{5}}$ an integer where $a_{i}$ are incredibly large integers?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, quadratics, integers

I have the equation with the following form:
$$n = \frac{a_{1}x^{2} + a_{2}x + a_{3}}{a_{4}x + a_{5}}$$
Where $a_{i}$ are incredibly large (e.g 1000 digits) but unrelated (not part of sequence or anything) known integers.

Problem: For an integer $x$, when is $n$ an integer?

Are there any known methods for solving this type of problem? My hope is that the solutions are not all just algorithms which stall with large integers.

EDIT* Since this is in reality a part of a larger problem, for this case, assume it always has a solution.

Comment: Well for one simple example, if $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are odd and $a_4,a_5$ are even, then $n$ is never an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By extended euclidean algorithm, you can reduce $\gcd(a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3,a_4x+a_5)$ into $\gcd(b_1x+b_2,b_3)$, from which it is easy (do some factoring and find modulo inverse if it exists).

For example, take $\frac{3x^2+7x-2}{x+7}$, then $$\begin{align*} \gcd(3x^2+7x-2,x+7)&=\gcd(3x^2+7x-2-3x(x+7),x+7)\\&=\gcd(-14x-2,x+7)\\&=\gcd(-14x-2+14(x+7),x+7)\\&=\gcd(96,x+7)\end{align*}$$

If we want $(x + 7) | (3x^2+7x-2)$, then $\gcd(x+7,3x^2+7x-2)=\gcd(x+7,96)=x+7$ i.e. $(x + 7) | 96$ i.e. $(x + 7)\in\{8, 12, 16, 24, 32, 48, 96\}$.

Comment: Does this work as well for very large integers? Especially the last part, seeing as we can't factor large (1000 digit) numbers.

Comment: @ChaosNyx The two problems are equivalent, meaning if you can solve one you can solve the other. If you can't factor the required number at the end, you probably can't find all $x$ efficiently - with all the $x$ you can recover factorisation.

Comment: So if I have $k = \frac{a}{bx + c}$, where $a,b$ and $c$ are very large, there is no effective way to find $x$ such that $k$ is an integer?

Comment: @ChaosNyx Unless I am missing something obvious, that is equivalent to factoring.